# UTF-8 char values in PHP

Tags: php, utf-8

I have a string like this:

```
$strUTF8 = 'ABCDAÄ';
```

How can I get the count of each character and its hex value ?

Example:

```
\x41 = 2 [A]
\x42 = 1 [B]
...
\xC3\x84 = 1 [Ä]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for($i = 0, $n = mb_strlen($strUTF8); $i < $n; $i++) {
    $mbchar = mb_substr($strUTF8, $i, 1);
    $numChars = strlen($mbchar);
    for($j = 0; $j < $numChars; $j++) {
        printf('%02x', ord($mbchar[$j]));
    }
    echo "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are only checking against UTF-8, you could use `mb_strlen`.

http://www.php.net/manual/de/function.mb-strlen.php

```
$strUTF8 = 'ABCDAÄ';
var_dump(mb_strlen($strUTF8, 'UTF-8')); // 6
```

To get all the ordinal values of your characters, iterare through the string and print the chars with `mb_substr`.

```
$strUTF8 = 'ABCDAÄ';
$len = mb_strlen($strUTF8, 'UTF-8');

for ($i = 0; $i < $len; $i++) {
    $chr = mb_substr($strUTF8, $i, 1, 'UTF-8');
    var_dump($chr, ord($chr));
}
```